# non static initializers strange behaviour

Tags: java, non-static

When I call this parameterized constructor with int value 0 this non static method is being called and shows its value as "Thal" but when I pass some int value say 3, this non static method is adding one element but this time the element is added is constructor type not non static method type, I'm confused.

Here is the code

```
public class Nimbu {
  public  static final long BLACK =0x000000;
  public  static final long GREEN =0x00FF00;
  public static String nimbuName;
  public long color = BLACK;

  public Nimbu(String nimbuName, long color) {
    this.nimbuName = nimbuName;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

public class NImbuKiBarni {
  public ArrayList<Nimbu> nimbus = new ArrayList<>();
  {        
    nimbus.add(new Nimbu("Thal", 0x00ff00));
  }    
}

public NImbuKiBarni(int nNImbu,String name,long color) {    
  for (int i = 1; i <=nNImbu ; i++) {
    nimbus.add(new Nimbu(name,color));
  }
}
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Nimbu> nimbus = new NImbuKiBarni(1,"Pankhu",0x00ffff).nimbus;
    for (Nimbu n :nimbus ) {
      System.out.println("from "+n.nimbuName +" and color is "+n.color);
    }
  }
}
```

Output with int value 0

```
The nimbu is from Thal and color is 65280
```

Output with int value 2

```
 The nimbu is from Pankhu and color is 65280
 The nimbu is from Pankhu and color is 65535
 The nimbu is from Pankhu and color is 65535
```

Comment: Please take the time to correctly indent the code before posting.

Comment: nimbuName is a *static* field. So all instances of your class share the same string. That is all there is to this.

Comment: @csmckelvey Sorry this was my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @GhostCat while debugging I noticed when non static function is initialized  'color' which is also a static member but a long value changes to 65280 and name to 'Thal' and when it comes back to the matched constructor to enter the for loop it changes the name to 'Pankhu' from 'Thal'but does not change the long value 'color' of 'nimbus' ,Why is this happening when both are static members,is it bcoz 'name' is a String value and since immutable? I did not understand this behavior.Plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems start here:

```
public static String nimbuName;
public long color = BLACK;
```

And then, in your unformatted constructor you do:

```
public  Nimbu(String nimbuName,long color)
{
  this.nimbuName = nimbuName;
  this.color = color;
}
```

Which is **bogus**. There is no point in using `this.nimbuNuame`. You declared that **field** to be **static**, therefore it is like "last wins". Meaning: when you create **multiple** Nimbu objects, then all these objects will have their *own* color field, but they are all **sharing** the **static** nimbuName field.

In other words: the compiler allows you to write down `this.nimbuName`, but what really happens is that you do `Nimbu.nimbuName` - because there is **no** specific "per this" nimbuName. There is only one string shared by all instances of the class.

That is all there is to this.

From that point of view, the real answer for you is to step back and study your material much more carefully. The real difference is how you declared those two fields. You are also mixing up terminology - you are not calling functions but a **constructor** which is by nature not static.